# How add an item to a member of List<> array?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

How can i add an item to a member of `List<>` array?
please see the example below :

```
List<string>[] array_of_lists = new List<string>[10];
array_of_lists[1].Add("some text here");
```

but a have the error below :

> *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

what this error mean and how can i fix it?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results

Comment: What is `int.Parse(txt_ParaCount_In_LinkScanner.Text)`'s value?

Comment: You don't need to make a list an array, a list is already an array, just do List<String> myList = new List<String();
Then do myList.Add("MyText");

Comment: please see my edit. for some reasons i need array of arrays...

Comment: Do you really need an array of type List<string>? Because that´s what you actually do, you build an array in which every entry itself is a list. For Twodimensional collection you´d rather use some kind of table or maybe a Dictionary as well...

Comment: Use a `List<List<string>>`

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so many edits, changes and commented answers I´d like to give a complete solution for you:

```
List<string>[] array_of_lists = new List<string>[10];
for (int i = 0; i < array_of_lists.Length; i++) {
    array_of_lists[i] = new List<string>();
    array_of_lists[i].Add("some text here");
    array_of_lists[i].Add("some other text here");
    array_of_lists[i].Add("and so on");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You have initialized the array, but all elements are `null` yet. If you want to initialize it with a `List<String>` at a given index you can't use `Add` which is a method of `List<T>`.

In this way you initalize the array at the second element:

```
array_of_lists[1] = new List<string>{"some text here"};
```

Note also that indices start with 0, not 1.

Here's a <kbd>[**demonstration**](http://ideone.com/ZGX0WD)</kbd>.

Comment: _start with 0, not 0_ Tiiiim :)

Comment: @SonerGönül: I've noticed it myself ;)

Comment: thanks, but how can i fix that null issue at define of array of List<>?

Comment: @MoonLight:There is no null issue with my code, so i guess that you haven't shown the relevant code. Maybe you are trying to add some items to the list which does not exist until you've initialized and added it to the array.

Comment: @MoonLight: I have added a working demonstration on ideone with your current code. So you should provide code that enables to reproduce the exception.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mixed `List<T>` and *arrays*.

From [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

> The `List<T>` class is the generic equivalent of the ArrayList class. It
>   implements the `IList<T>` generic interface **using an array whose size is
>   dynamically increased as required.**

So, easyly you can write,

```
List<string> array_of_lists = new List<string>();
array_of_lists.Add("some text here");
```

Comment: but i need an specific part of my array (mean 1 or 9) to add an item and my array length should be 10.

Answer (score 1):

problem is that when you initialize an array, it is created with default values of items. For most of the value types (int, float, vs... ) default value will be 0. for reference types (strings and nullable and List and many other) default value will be null.

so your code should be like this

```
List<string>[] list_lines_link_scanner_ar = new List<string>[int.Parse(txt_ParaCount_In_LinkScanner.Text)];

// this is the line -->
list_lines_link_scanner_ar[1] = new new List<string>();
//  <----
list_lines_link_scanner_ar[1].Add("some text here");
```

Comment: ok, that null issue was the problem. but should i do list_lines_link_scanner_ar[?] = new new List<string>(); for every part of my array?

Comment: Yes, just use for or foreach.

Comment: @MoonLight : yes you have to since every member of array is null. try using another list for lists and add them when you require them. and an array of lists is smelling. What exactly are you after? @FallenSquirrel : foreach? every item is already null, ìn `foreach `(var item in list_lines)`, item will always be null and foreach variable cannot be set.

Answer (score -1):

Declare:

```
List<List<string>> listOfList = new List<List<string>>();
```

Add:

```
listOfList.Add(new List<string> { "s1", "s2", "s3" });
```

unless you really need an array.

Comment: Thats an array not a list. An array has no `Add` method.